# Flutter SinglechildScrollView widget Overflow

Tags: android, flutter

I'm encountering an issue where a SingleChildScrollView in Flutter is overflowing from its parent Container. Despite setting constraints and trying different approaches, the SingleChildScrollView does not stay within the bounds of its parent. The content within the SingleChildScrollView extends beyond the specified height, causing overflow.
The first screen is an error state and the second screen is also a state which overflows or goes up .

[image][image]

I just want the the scrollView to be a normal dropdown menu which covers some part of the screen in to shows options .

```
Padding(
            padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
            child: Center(
              child: Column(
                // mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
                children: [
                  Expanded(
                      flex: 1,
                      child: Column(
                        children: [
                          const Text(
                            "Find A Course For You",
                            style: TextStyle(
                                fontSize: 30,
                                color: Color(0XFF004aad),
                                fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
                          ),
                          Row(
                            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                            children: [
                              Padding(
                                padding: const EdgeInsets.all(2.0),
                                child: Container(
                                  decoration: BoxDecoration(
                                    borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10),
                                    border: Border.all(
                                      color: const Color(0XFF5271ff),
                                      width: 2,
                                    ),
                                  ),
                                  child: DropdownButtonHideUnderline(
                                    child: DropdownButton2(
                                      hint: const Text("Select Term"),
                                      items: term
                                          .map((item) =>
                                              DropdownMenuItem<String>(
                                                value: item,
                                                child: Text(
                                                  item,
                                                  style: const TextStyle(
                                                    fontSize: 14,
                                                  ),
                                                ),
                                              ))
                                          .toList(),
                                      value: selectedTerm,
                                      onChanged: (value) {
                                        print("value changed to ${value}");
                                        setState(() {
                                          selectedTerm = value as String;
                                        });
                                      },
                                    ),
                                  ),
                                ),
                              ),
                              Padding(
                                padding: const EdgeInsets.all(2.0),
                                child: Container(
                                  decoration: BoxDecoration(
                                    borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10),
                                    border: Border.all(
                                      color: const Color(0XFF5271ff),
                                      width: 2,
                                    ),
                                  ),
                                  child: DropdownButtonHideUnderline(
                                    child: DropdownButton2(
                                      hint: const Text("Select Quarter"),
                                      items: quarter.keys
                                          .toList()
                                          .map((item) =>
                                              DropdownMenuItem<String>(
                                                value: item,
                                                child: Text(
                                                  item,
                                                  style: const TextStyle(
                                                    fontSize: 14,
                                                  ),
                                                ),
                                              ))
                                          .toList(),
                                      value: selectedQuarter,
                                      onChanged: (value) {
                                        print("value changed to ${value}");
                                        setState(() {
                                          selectedQuarter = value as String;
                                        });
                                      },
                                    ),
                                  ),
                                ),
                              )
                            ],
                          ),
                          TextField(
                            onChanged: filterSuggestions,
                            controller: searchController,
                            decoration: InputDecoration(
                              suffixIcon: IconButton(
                                  onPressed: () {
                                    clearSearch();
                                  },
                                  icon: const Icon(Icons.clear)),
                              hintText: "Search",
                              border: OutlineInputBorder(
                                  borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(20.0),
                                  borderSide: const BorderSide(
                                      color: Color(0XFF5271ff))),
                            ),
                          ),
                          Expanded(
                              child: ListView.builder(
                                  itemCount: filteredSuggestions.length,
                                  itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                                    final suggestion =
                                        filteredSuggestions[index];
                                    return Padding(
                                      padding: const EdgeInsets.all(5.0),
                                      child: ListTile(
                                        tileColor: Colors.blueAccent[400],
                                        onTap: () {
                                          selectedDepartment =
                                              suggestion['Code'];
                                          searchController.text =
                                              suggestion['Code']!;
                                          clearSearch();
                                          setState(() {
                                            _searched = true;
                                          });
                                        },
                                        title: Text(suggestion['Department']!),
                                      ),
                                    );
                                  })),
```

This is my code for the same.

Comment: try with removing `fex` and cant see `SingleChildScrollView` on your snippet